# Error after deleting an argument (the "method arguments" error)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, constructor, arguments

I have built a class called "MemoryDB" (whose c'tor takes 6 arguments) and created unit-test for her.
Everything was OK until today - I tried deleting one of the arguments, so they remain 5. Even though (after re-building, saving, re-creating the class MemoryDB, etc.), the unit-test does not recognize the change and the error message appears: `TimeTable.DB.MemoryDB does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments.`
I also tried to re-create the unit-test, but for some reason the automatic c'tor it creates is the old c'tor, with 6 arguments.

Have I deleted the argument in a wrong way? How can I fix this? Do other errors in the project might cause this weird problem?

p.s. here is the old c'tor:

```
    public MemoryDB(List<Grade> allGrades, List<Teacher> allTeachers, ForbiddenHours forbiddenHours, List<Group> allGroups, List<List<Teacher>> staffs, List<List<Group>> parallelGroups)
    {
        CheckParametersValidation(allGrades, allTeachers, forbiddenHours, allGroups, staffs, parallelGroups);

        this.allGrades = allGrades;
        this.allTeachers = allTeachers;
        this.forbiddenHours = forbiddenHours;
        this.allGroups = allGroups;
        this.staffs = staffs;
        this.parallelGroups = parallelGroups;
    }
```

the new c'tor, after deleting "forbiddenHours":

```
    public MemoryDB(List<Grade> allGrades, List<Teacher> allTeachers, List<Group> allGroups, List<List<Teacher>> staffs, List<List<Group>> parallelGroups)
    {
        CheckParametersValidation(allGrades, allTeachers, allGroups, staffs, parallelGroups);

        this.allGrades = allGrades;
        this.allTeachers = allTeachers;
        this.allGroups = allGroups;
        this.staffs = staffs;
        this.parallelGroups = parallelGroups;
    }
```

Comment: How are you creating your unit tests? How is the library referenced in the unit test project?

Comment: The unit-test is in a different project - "TestProject1" - and have this line: `using TimeTable.DB;`

Comment: How did you add the reference to the library (you explained about the `using` statement - that's a different thing) - as a project or as a DLL?

Comment: Did you rebuild the project before trying to make changes to the unit tests? Try that first.

Comment: Yes, I rebuild almost every second (by the way, thank you for your attention :))

Comment: Could be some caching issue. Did you restart Visual Studio? And does the library actually build? You are not getting errors?

Comment: Yes (restarting). I tried to start the deleting of the argument again (this time by right-clicking on the metohd and refactoring) and recreated a unit-test. Again he created 6 argument c'tor but now an error for 6 arguments is shown (in red), When I delete the forbiddenHours parameter,  the error for 5 arguments is shown (in blue)...

Comment: Did you check the parameter list - are the parameters of the right types in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell *why* this happens, but there are certain things to look for when troubleshooting such an issue:

- If the library was referenced as a DLL, it is possible that the DLL has not been updated.

  - If that's the case, rebuild the library - if there are any errors, it has not built. Fix the errors.
  - Once rebuilt, remove the existing reference and re-add it (not strictly needed, you can simply replace the DLL on the file system)
- If the library was referenced as a project:

  - Make sure the library is building without errors.
  - It is possible that some caching issues are going on. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! The problem was other errors in the project (without any reasonable connection to what I've working on). I suppose that test files do not work well with errors around... Again, thank you! :)

Comment: @Lee - The project needs to _build_ before the DLL is updated and changes can be seen by other projects (such as the unit test project).